# All other things being equal meaning an if clause or when clause

Tags: grammar

{All other things being equal}, the student prefers to tell stories about 17th century Christian paintings.

Should I understand the phrase in the bracket as an if clause or a when clause?

Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Comment: I think most speakers make hardly any distinction between _if_ and _when_ in many cases. Can you elaborate how an answer would influence your interpretation of the given sentence?

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer.   Your explanation already answered my question.  Thanks.

Comment: Neither -- it's a non-finite clause functioning as a supplement.